# Will an azure function with a Service Bus Queue trigger which processes messages in batches be triggered instantaneously?

Tags: azure, azure-functions, azureservicebus, azure-servicebus-queues

Basically the title, if I have an Azure Function which is being triggered by a queue and I have also set that function to process messages in batch will it wait for the batch to build or if I put the message now it will be processed instantaneously?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Function will not wait for the exact batch size to accumulate to trigger your code. Once messages are available l, the function will be triggered.